# After upgrading android build:gradle:4.0.0 shows me error in proguard

Tags: android, build.gradle, proguard

After upgrading android build:gradle:4.0.0 shows me **Unresolved class name** error in proguard.

```
-keep class rx.** { *; } // unresolve
-keep class org.apache.** {*;} // unresolve
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; } // unresolve
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; } // unresolve
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8 // error at $ sign
```

So how to fix these errors, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Did not find the solution, but I add to proguard rules:

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
```

At least its now working.

(Its far from ideal...)

Comment: no, I just remove a single star, but that is not a solution, let me check what happen later.